# Change value of a variable inside foreach loop? Make it available outside the loop

Tags: javascript

I'm setting an initial flag then doing a foreach which changes the flag to a different value but outside the foreach loop I still see the original flag. As if nothing changed. But it did change inside the foreach loop

The value is only changed inside the foreach loop, but not outside of it..

I saw a number of similar questions but they all deal with the actual array values, in this case it's a simple variable outside of the foreach loop.

```
    var arr = ["one"];

    var str = 0;

    arr.forEach(function(part){

        if(part == 'one') {
            var str = 1;
            console.log('str changed to: ' + str);
        }

    })

    console.log('str is now: ' + str);
```

This will return

```
str changed to: 1
str is now: 0
```

Based on my PHP logic above should return "**str is now: 1**", why does it have the original value of 0?

Comment: when you declare `var str` inside the loop you're creating a new variable, not reassigning the one outside the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are re-declaring the variable with `var` in the loop instead of just updating/setting it. Re-declaring it wipes out the earlier variable of the same name from the previous loop iteration and hides the one from the function in the higher scope. It establishes a new one instead of just updating the value in the existing one.

```js
var arr = ["one"];
var str = 0;
arr.forEach(function(part){
 if(part == 'one') {
   str = 1;
   console.log('str changed to: ' + str);
 }
})

console.log('str is now: ' + str);
```

Comment: got it thank you, just curios why is a redeclared str not available outside the loop?

Comment: @RobertSinclair It is available outside of the loop, but only after the loop is complete. You can't access a variable prior to it being created.

Comment: i see, i'm guessing it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of JS?

Comment: @RobertSinclair No, it's about scope. Variables declared with `var` are scoped to the function that they are declared inside of. In your case, that would be the anonymous function passed to the `.forEach()`. Since that function isn't available outside of the loop, neither is it's local variables (unless we get into closures), but in general, if you declare a variable with `var` in a loop, it will be available in that function at any point after the loop ends.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: *Re-declaring it wipes out the earlier variable* No.

Comment: In the context of the question this is irrelevant and anyone would interpret that as *wipes out the outer `str`*.

Comment: @connexo Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're declaring a *new* `str` variable inside of `forEach`. Just drop the `var` and it will work.

```js
var arr = ["one"];
var str = 0;

arr.forEach(function(part) {
  if (part == 'one') {
    str = 1; // Notice the lack of var
    console.log('str changed to: ' + str);
  }
});

console.log('str is now: ' + str);
```

Comment: got it thank you, just curios why is a redeclared str not available outside the loop?

Comment: @RobertSinclair Because variables are scoped to each function (or global). When you declare a variable inside of a function then that variable is available inside of the function. If there were any variables declared outside of that function with the same name then they are "shadowed".

Comment: @RobertSinclair I'd recommend [doing some reading on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for a better explanation.

Comment: aahh.. okey .. great explanation thank you! I should have paid closer attention to the final '})'; Makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 1):

Just as an additional answer that wants to suggest a different way to do what you are doing with `forEach`:

`Array.prototype.some()` does a good job here. It tests if any array element satisfies the condition in the callback function you pass to it.

```js
let arr = ["two", "one", 7];
let str = 0;

str = arr.some(part => part === 'one') ? 1 : str;

console.log('str is now: ' + str);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the actual question being asked?

Comment: @Scott Added clarification on that.

Answer (score 1):

buddy you are doing the same mistake I was making don't initialize variable inside foreach loop.

i.e.
use
str = 1;
instead of
var str = 1;

inside if of your for loop

Answer (score 0):

So I had this challenge where I needed to await a query in a forEach loop and it was giving me issues. So I just had to use a for...of instead of forEach.

```
let answers = [
    {
        questionId: "questionId1",
        answer: "answer1",
    },
    {
        questionId: "questionId2",
        answer: "answer2",
    }
]
```

Now I used a forEach loop and I needed to query inside the forEach loop. So what I did was use a for of instead of forEach like

Previously

```
let score = 0
let question
answers.forEach(async(obj) => {
    // Query obj.questionId here
    question = await Question.findOne({id: obj.questionId)
    if(obj.answer == question.answer){
        score += 1
    }
})
console.log(score)
```

In my case, the above didn't work because the score being logged above prolly got executed before the response from the question queries were received.

Now

```
let score = 0
let question
for(obj of answers){
    question = await Question.findOne({id: obj.questionId)
    if(obj.answer == question.answer){
        score += 1
    }
}
console.log(score)
```

In the end I was happy and that's all I needed to do. So why not use for of instead of forEach and be happy too. Lol